# How to count the words in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [count words in pdf file](https://superuser.com/questions/221359/count-words-in-pdf-file)

I have a big PDF file with a lot of pictures, tables, etc. I want to count the words of this document. How can I do this in Windows?

Until now I just found solutions for Unix or solutions that require to download a big application. Isn't there an easy way?